# Ethernet with DHCP not working

Tags: debian, ethernet, dhcp

I'm trying to get internet on my beaglebone black with ubuntu, but it won't work. My /etc/network/interfaces file has:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

in it. Should I use static IP or something?

*update:*

Now it just randomly works... Did a reset of ubuntu and a couple reboots and then it just worked... Thanks for all of your help

Comment: I don't know about beaglebone boards, but I do know that default ubuntu should come with dhclient and NetworkManager. You do not need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` unless you are going to use your board as some form of server.

Comment: Can you watch the network traffic with `tcpdump` or `wireshark`? Do you have a dhcp-server at all?

Comment: I don't know about any of this but I got this thing as a present and just want to use internet :/

Comment: Dhcp seemed easier than static ip

Comment: Command line, I'm trying to download ubuntu-desktop xD

Comment: The latest port for beaglebone black

Comment: @ott-- It doesn't know those commands

Comment: Have you checked that whatever dhcp client this distro uses is running (ps aux), and whether your ethernet interface is actually named eth0 (ifconfig -a)?

Comment: Ps aux: gives a giant list

Comment: Ifconfig -a includes eth0

Answer (score 0):

You probably still need to actually restart that interface for the changes to take affect. `ifup eth0` will do the trick.

Comment: It says it's already configured

Comment: what about `ifdown eth0` then `ifup eth0`?. Alternatively you could also reboot for any config changes to take affect as well.

Comment: I didn't change the config it was like this

Comment: let's try a reboot then if the ethernet cable is connected and dhcp is configured on the interface `shutdown -r now`

Comment: I tried rebooting and fully disabling a couple of times

Answer (score 0):

Using a lamobo r1 and armbian here. Your problem should be in U-boot; either you have to configure it, or you will find in the first partition a file already pre-made for it. i would suggest you investigate a bit more of U-Boot and the corresponding tools. ARM servers often have problems using hardware because it has to be activated there.

Comment: Why would it disable ethernet on that?

Comment: Have a look at an example for my machine. Activating all sort of stuff before booting up the actual kernel. https://github.com/igorpecovnik/lib/blob/next/config/lamobo-r1.fex

Comment: The actual ROM is minimalistic, the software in first partition of the MicroSD card has to initialise hardware and load up the kernel. In the NetBSD and  Linux images I tested you had in the first partition ready made files for some common SBCs, that you had to move over the default ones.